# How to log the name of the each it-test in Protractor

Tags: jasmine, protractor

Assume the tests look like this

```
describe("suite-1", ()=>{
  it("test1",()=> {
   ...
  }
  it("test2",()=> {
   ...
  }
}
```

I would like to output the name of each test in STDOUT, somewhat more generic than in each of its it() clauses. It is probably a case for reporter. Are there any standard reporters for this already?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what your current output looks like and what you *want* it to look like?

Comment: In any case, I think this package may be what you are looking for https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-reporters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Huzzah!

## Jasmine Custom Reporters

You will need to create a custom Jasmine reporter. Put the following snippet in your Protractor configuration file in the onPrepare hook. I've tried the following and it works:

```
onPrepare: () => {
  myReporter = {
      suiteStarted: function(result) {
        console.log('Suite started: ' + result.description);
      },
      specStarted: function(result) {
        console.log('Spec started: ' + result.description);
      }
    };
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(myReporter);
  }
```

You can read more about custom reporters on the [Jasmine docs site](https://jasmine.github.io/2.5/custom_reporter.html)

## Example:

This is my spec:

```
import {browser} from 'protractor';

describe('our first Protractor test', () => {
  it('should load a page and verify the url', () => {
    browser.get('https://angularjs.org/');
    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual('https://angularjs.org/');
  });
});
```

This is my console output:

```
[18:37:52] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[18:37:52] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
Started
Suite started: our first Protractor test
Spec started: should load a page and verify the url
.


1 spec, 0 failures
Finished in 2.541 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

[jasmine-spec-reporter](https://github.com/bcaudan/jasmine-spec-reporter) could suit your need, it outputs results to stdout this way:

```
Spec started

  suite 1
    ✓ test 1
    ✗ test 2
      - Expected true to be false.
    ✓ test 3
```